# How to make multiple update in django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, web

I'm trying to make multiple update in django by checking in checkbox then push the update button.

This is my view.py

```
def update_kel_stat(request, id, kelid):
    if request.method == "POST":
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql = "UPDATE keluargapeg_dipkeluargapeg SET KelStatApprov='3' WHERE (PegUser = %s AND KelID=%s )" % (id, kelid,)
        cursor.execute(sql)
```

where 'id' is user parameter and 'kelid' is row paramater where 'kelid' become multiple parameter.

This is my url.py

```
url(r'^karyawan/update_status/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<kelid>\d+)/$', views.pesan_update, name='update_pesan')
```

template.html, I use JavaScript to load url where use to update

```
    <script>
    function setDeleteAction() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete these rows?")) {
            document.kel.action = "{% url 'update_pesan' %}";
            document.kel.submit();
        }
    }
</script>

<form method="post" action="" name="kel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% for keluarga in kels %}
    <tr id="{{ keluarga.KelID }}">
        <td>
            <a href="#">{{ keluarga.KelNamaLengkap }}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{ keluarga.KelHubungan }}</td>
        <td class="hidden-480">{{ keluarga.KelTglLahir }}</td>
        <td>{{ keluarga.KelJenisKel }}</td>
        <td class="hidden-480">{{ keluarga.KelIjazahAkhir }}
        </td>
        <td>{{ keluarga.KelPekerjaan }}</td>
        {% if keluarga.KelStatApprov == '1' %}
            <td><span
                    class="label label-sm label-danger">Draft</span>
            </td>
        {% elif keluarga.KelStatApprov == '2' %}
            <td>
                <span class="label label-sm label-warning">Revisi</span>
            </td>
        {% elif keluarga.KelStatApprov == '3' %}
            <td>
                <span class="label label-sm label-success">Setuju</span>
            </td>
        {% endif %}
        <td>{{ keluarga.KelKetRevisi }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="
                    {{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ keluarga.KelFileUpload }}">{{ keluarga.KelNamaFile }}</a>
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="kel[]"
                   value="{{ keluarga.KelID }}"></td>
        <td>
            <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs action-buttons">
                <a class="green"
                   href="{% url 'edit_keluarga' keluarga.PegUser keluarga.KelID %}">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-130"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="red" href="#">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
<tr>
    <td>
        <button type="button" name="btn_delete" id="btn_delete"
                class="btn btn-success"
                onClick="setDeleteAction();">Approve
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can I get multiple row(like array in php) in view and url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

were you looking for [getlist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)?

> QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None)
>   Returns the data with the
>   requested key, as a Python list. Returns an empty list if the key
>   doesn’t exist and no default value was provided. It’s guaranteed to
>   return a list of some sort unless the default value provided is not a
>   list.

```
request.POST.getlist('kel')
```